# valloc identifier not found on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, malloc, identifier

I have to modify a Mac code to make it work on Windows, or at least compile for now, but there seems to be a problem with valloc.

It says : `error C3861: 'valloc': identifier not found.`

This is how it's used :

```
#ifndef _XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED 1
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED 1
#endif
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <queue>
#include "ArrayArithmetic.h"
#include "MessageObject.h"

#if __SSE__
// allocate memory aligned to 16-bytes memory boundary
#define ALLOC_ALIGNED_BUFFER(_numBytes) (float *) _mm_malloc(_numBytes, 16)
#define FREE_ALIGNED_BUFFER(_buffer) _mm_free(_buffer)
#else
// NOTE(mhroth): valloc seems to work well, but is deprecated!
#define ALLOC_ALIGNED_BUFFER(_numBytes) (float *) valloc(_numBytes)
#define FREE_ALIGNED_BUFFER(_buffer) free(_buffer)
#endif
```

I have the good include, or at least I think so.
No, I really don't see where it comes from, is `valloc` available on Windows?

I work on windows 8.1 with Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: You should tag language. I would guess C but you are including `<queue>`.

Comment: "The `valloc()` function allocates size bytes of memory and returns a pointer to the allocated memory. The allocated memory is aligned on a page boundary." [(source)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/valloc.3.html). If page alignment is important in this code (and who knows?) you'll have to write a substitute.

Comment: .. this may help for Windows: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10862121/undefined-reference-to-posix-memalign-using-mingw32

Comment: I've edited your title (and made a few other fixes). Referring to `valloc` as `Valloc` is confusing; they're two distinct identifiers.

Comment: FWIW, `valloc()` is considered deprecated. You should be using `posix_memalign()` instead...

Answer (score 1):

If Windows is detected, use the [`_aligned_malloc`/`_aligned_free`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z34s9c6.aspx) functions.

```
#ifdef _WIN32

#define ALLOC_ALIGNED_BUFFER(_numBytes) ((float *)_aligned_malloc (_numBytes, 16))
#define FREE_ALIGNED_BUFFER(_buffer) _aligned_free(_buffer)

#elif __SSE__
// allocate memory aligned to 16-bytes memory boundary
#define ALLOC_ALIGNED_BUFFER(_numBytes) (float *) _mm_malloc(_numBytes, 16)
#define FREE_ALIGNED_BUFFER(_buffer) _mm_free(_buffer)
#else
// NOTE(mhroth): valloc seems to work well, but is deprecated!
#define ALLOC_ALIGNED_BUFFER(_numBytes) (float *) valloc(_numBytes)
#define FREE_ALIGNED_BUFFER(_buffer) free(_buffer)
#endif
```